# Converting a list into a specific string with Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, type-conversion

I have this piece of code...:

```
c_ids = [2323,4343,534]
ids = " &drags[][id]=".join(str(x) for x in c_ids)

print ids 
# 2323 &drags[][id]=4343 &drags[][id]=534
```

How can I make it to print:

```
&drags[][id]=2323 &drags[][id]=4343 &drags[][id]=534
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to ignore the fact you are adding in spaces here; that's probably not what you want but easily removed from the output.

Format each element and join with an empty string:

```
''.join(' &drags[][id]={}'.format(x) for x in c_ids)
```

or avoid reinventing the URL encoding wheel and use the [`urllib.urlencode()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) instead:

```
'&' + urllib.urlencode({'drags[][id]': c_ids}, doseq=True)
```

The `doseq` flag enables converting list values into separate elements in the resulting query string; each `id` in `c_ids` is encoded separately.

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> c_ids = [2323,4343,534]
>>> '&' + urllib.urlencode({'drags[][id]': c_ids}, doseq=True)
'&drags%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=2323&drags%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=4343&drags%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=534'
```

The encoding of the square brackets is entirely correct here; any compliant web server will decode those again (PHP and Ruby-on-Rails included).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know about urlencode.It's just right.